# Set Multi-Select Choice Columns using with jQuery In SPD 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

In my list I added Choice control. In this control I add multiple values I want set predefined using jQuery.

Please check attachment. I want to when page load that two check boxes are selected automatically.

```
$("input[id^='Product1_'][id*='_MultiChoiceOption_']").each(function(){         
////
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code for your requirements:

```
    jQuery(function(){
      jQuery("span.ms-RadioText[title='Education'] input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", "checked");
      jQuery("span.ms-RadioText[title='Retail'] input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", "checked");
    })
```

Selector `span.ms-RadioText[title='Education'] input[type=checkbox]` selects your particular checkbox by using checkbox value.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply  this is my loop how to select in this loop only Retail and Edu    $("input[id^='Product1_'][id*='_MultiChoiceOption_']").each(function(){ alert("hi")});

Comment: You don't need loop for this, just use selectors I proposed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , you can achecive this using placing below jquery in document.ready function

This multiple chocie control renders in the below format , so you can find the id of the particular option you want to check it by default.

```
<input id="Vertical_a8554df1-914b-483a-9ebd-43c92c17ad03_MultiChoiceOption_5" type="checkbox">
<label for="PRID_a8554df1-914b-483a-9ebd-43c92c17ad03_MultiChoiceOption_5">Education</label>

//put this in document.ready function
//This you can use to checkthe specific checkbox using its id
$('#Vertical_a8554df1-914b-483a-9ebd-43c92c17ad03_MultiChoiceOption_5').prop("checked", true);
```